# ping command does not work without extension

Tags: windows, command-line, ping

all of a sudden my command prompt commands started giving problems.
when I run ping.exe it works but when I run ping it says, 'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

same behavior for ipconifg and some other commands.

Comment: Check `set PATHEXT` command output; it should return something similar to `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

Comment: great, working, thanks, i did not know about PATHEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [PATHEXT environment variable](http://environmentvariables.org/PathExt) article:

> `PathExt` environment variable returns a list of the file extensions
>   that the operating system considers to be executable. When executing a
>   command line that does not contain an extension, the command
>   interpreter (`cmd.exe`) uses the value of this environment variable to
>   determine which extensions to look for and in what order.

To restore broken variable(s), read and follow [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)